# How to group by name in PROC SQL for SAS (returns error message)

Tags: sql, group-by, sas, type-conversion, proc-sql

Basically let's say I have this data set, p1:

```
Name  Order_Value
John  5
John  11
John  7
Mark  5
Mark  7
```

I want to output this result:

```
 Name  Total_Spent
 John  23
 Mark  12
```

This is the code I'm attempting to use:

```
PROC SQL;

SELECT name, SUM(order_value) AS Total_Spent
FROM p1
GROUP BY name;
QUIT;
```

It just returns the error message:
 ERROR: The NAME keyword will have a constant value for all rows in a query. It is not supported on the ORDER BY or GROUP BY clauses.

How can I group it so that it will output the desired result?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the query, so it has to be the operating environment.  If you restart SAS does the message continue to appear ?  What other data or proc steps are before and after in the actual code ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I simply imported it as a CSV file. Using this code

    proc import datafile=practice
     out=p1
     dbms=csv
     replace;
     getnames=YES;
run;


That's the only code I have in the program. Is there maybe something wrong with the import? (I used filename to minimize the directory of the import to just "practice). When I do SELECT *, it populates normally.  EDIT 3: And yes, restarted SAS, same issue.

Comment: What happens if you use `p1.name` instead of `name`

Comment: That worked! I should probably make it a habit to specify the data set when referencing columns. Thanks :)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fully qualify the column-name using syntax ***table-name.column***

@Tester_Y, The error message

```
ERROR: The NAME keyword will have a constant value for all rows in a query.
It is not supported on the ORDER BY or GROUP BY clauses.
```

is not one I have encountered before.  These kinds of 'what the bleep?' errors *can* occur in SAS sessions that are running code via DATA step `call execute` or within complicated macro generated code involving atypical macro quoting.

The poster states the error is repeatable across SAS session restarts and at the start of a fresh session.  This is significant because there is little chance of prior code complicating the attempted query.

The peculiarity is that `name` is not a reserved word in `Proc SQL` and the code does not demonstrate errant semi-colons.  Regardless, the OP sample code and error indicates `Proc SQL` is parsing the statements (in Tester_Y's session) such that it thinks `NAME` is a keyword.

The solution for Tester is to fully qualify the column-name using syntax ***table-name.column***

The following sample code **does not** have the same ERROR as OP stated, which makes me think Tester's next likely suspects are some hidden code (autoexec/EG connection), encoding issue, system option, or a platform related issue.

```
data _null_;
  file "c:\temp\p1.txt";
  put "Name,Order_Value";
  put "John,5";
  put "John,11";
  put "John,7";
  put "Mark,5";
  put "Mark,7";
run;

proc import datafile='c:\temp\p1.txt' dbms=csv replace out=p1;
  getnames = yes;
run;

PROC SQL;
SELECT name, SUM(order_value) AS Total_Spent
FROM p1
GROUP BY name;
QUIT;


PROC SQL DQUOTE=ANSI;
SELECT "name", SUM(order_value) AS Total_Spent
FROM p1
GROUP BY "name";
QUIT;
```

Comment: Makes sense! I thought it was possibly because I was using SAS University Edition, but I guess that's not it. Thanks for the detailed response-- I was just perplexed because I couldn't figure out for the life of me why the code wasn't working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen SAS do that for the variable `NAME`,

```
61    proc sql;
62     select name,sum(age)
63     from sashelp.class
64     group by name
65     ;
66     quit;
NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL used (Total process time):
      real time           0.10 seconds
      cpu time            0.07 seconds
```

but there are some specific variable names, like `USER` that do cause trouble.

```
67    proc sql;
68     select user,sum(age)
69     from sashelp.class(rename=(name=user))
70     group by user
71     ;
ERROR: The USER keyword will have a constant value for all rows in a query. It is not 
       supported on the ORDER BY or GROUP BY clauses.
72     quit;
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
```

Adding an alias prefix to the reference can prevent that confusion.

```
73    proc sql;
74     select a.user,sum(age)
75     from sashelp.class(rename=(name=user)) a
76     group by a.user
77     ;
78     quit;
NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL used (Total process time):
      real time           0.03 seconds
      cpu time            0.03 seconds
```

Comment: PROC SQL and the ANSI Standard - discusses Reserved Words http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002473705.htm (9.2 Docs)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  `NAME` is not mentioned as a reserved word in that document.